# Mysql not logging in a new mysq.log file

Tags: mysql, logging

I've enabled logging in my dev environment as follows:

```
 general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
 general_log             = 1
```

but the problem is whenever the server creates a new mysql.log file, the new log doesn't record the mysql activities i have to restart the mysql service and then its starts logging activities but being on production i cannot everyday restart mysql service. i have also checked the newly created mysql.log file its mysql:adm.

Comment: why mysql is creating new log file...mysql will not change log file itlself it will save query log in this file always...

Comment: mysql creates a new file when the file reaches a certain size. eg 3gb

Comment: I think it will max. file size limit in your system as there is no limit of general query log in mysql....further let me know how many days it takes to write 3 GB data.